# Recurrence Relation Homework question 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

This is a HW question.

Find a recurrence relation for $b_n, n \geq 0 $where $b_n$ is the number of ways to partition $s= {1,2,3,...n}$ into exactly 2 subsets.

I am looking for a hint on how to go about this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** There are two interpretations of the problem: (1) any subsets will do or (2) the subsets must be non-empty. We deal with (1). Of course (2) is a close relative.

Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ people into $2$ subsets. Subset is too abstract a term, call them **teams**.  Now an $(n+1)$-th person comes along, George.

We can divide our $(n+1)$-element set into teams by dividing the original $n$-element set into teams, and adding George to *one of the teams or the other*. Thus $a_{n+1}=\dots$.

Comment: I like this answer a lot! +1. :)

Comment: Reading your answer and AWertheim's answer I believe the answer should be $a_{n+1}=2*a_n$.. If I am wrong then just say so and I will keep thinking about it :)

Comment: You are perfectly right.

Comment: thanks for your help Andre

Comment: You are welcome. You will notice that both answers you refer to try to make the problem more concrete, one by talking about teams, the other by using bit strings, that is, "words."

Answer (score 3):

Hint: form a bijection with bit strings. Let $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ be the subsets. Let the string $(a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, \ldots, a_{n})$ mean the following: If $a_{i} = 1$, then $i \in S_{1}$; if $a_{i} = 0$, then $i \in S_{2}$. We can see that this bit string completely determines the partition on $1, 2, \ldots, n$. So $b_{n}$ should count the number of distinct bit strings we can form.

Now, say we expand to the $n+1$th number. Our bit string expands to $(a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, \ldots, a_{n}, a_{n+1})$. To get $b_{n+1}$, we again count bit strings - but if we know $b_{n}$ we can see that we can put $b_{n+1}$ in terms of $b_{n}$ by the following relation: $b_{n+1}$ = (choices for $a_{n+1}$)*$b_{n}$.

Now can you get $b_{n+1}$ in terms of $b_{n}$?

Comment: Your answer also gives a nice concrete representation of the choices.

Comment: thanks for your help AWetheim,  your hint/answer was very helpful.

Comment: My pleasure, Kj Tada! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

why dont you start with writing out $b_n$ for the first $n$ such as $1,2,3,4$ and then see how it looks for $b_n$ and then for $b_{n+1}$. Then just substituting in $b_{n+1}$ the right side with $b_n$.